# Packaging oracle database rows and columns as bytes

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, jdbc

I am new to Java and I am looking for a way to package the data retrieved from oracle database  as bytes. I am thinking of packaging the data as I read them from the database using JDBC. Unfortunately I wont know the number of rows I am going to get from the database. So the size is not fixed and hence I realized I can't use byte array. I found that ByteArrayOutputStream along with DataOutputStream can be used along with it. I would also like to read them back by each column and row.

I am would like to be able to do something like this:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream w = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    w.writeInt(5);
    w.writeInt(13);
    w.write("A string value");
    w.write(Oracle Timestamp);
    byte[] ba = bos.toByteArray();
```

And I should be able to read each value later which I am not sure how to do. For example I tried ByteArrayInputStream and DataInputStream  but don't see how to read the timestamp or string either.

Am I doing it the right way? or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Bytes?  Is this a trick question?  Everything in Java is represented as bytes under the covers.You should use JDBC to map your database values into objects that make sense, not bytes.  Java is an object-oriented language.  Why don't you make your real problem clearer.  What are you trying to accomplish that makes you think this byte approach is the best way to do it?

Comment: Yes, ditto.  Feels like an XY problem.  Try to tell us what problem you think you are actually trying to solve.  If you want literal byte data, the BLOB data type is your go-to.  See also Apache DBUtils, an easy light-weight ORM.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am writing a WebService that retrieves data from Oracle database . Once I retrieve  the data I need to send it across to the client as an array of bytes. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Those are all details you'd need to include in your question, and in my experience webservices usually don't just use 'bytes', binary webservices require a specific format (eg protobuf). Find out what that format is, if there is specific tooling for it and use it.

Comment: Thank you! I looked into protobuf and looks like it will solve the problem!